# I have an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : on a getJSON call. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, rest

I use a restfull api
http://applications.opap.gr/DrawsRestServices/kino/last.json

This url returns in json format the **"numbers games"** that have won in a game called **"kino"**

the results in browser is something like this:

```
{"draw":{"drawTime":"18-04-2014T10:15:00","drawNo":437017,"results":[6,9,12,16,17,21,24,26,31,36,38,53,54,55,61,63,67,69,75,79]}}
```

I am trying to get these numbers by using a **jquery function**:

```
function get_game_results_json() {
$.getJSON("http://applications.opap.gr/DrawsRestServices/kino/last.json?callback=?", function(result){
   alert(result);
});
}
```

a) **My first problem** is that when I go to the tab **console** of google chrome 
I have "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :** "

But att the same time in the tab **network** I have a response that looks it works

```
draw: {drawTime:18-04-2014T10:20:00, drawNo:437018,…}
  drawNo: 437018
  drawTime: "18-04-2014T10:20:00"
  results: [6, 8, 15, 28, 32, 33, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 50, 58, 59, 68, 69, 72, 75, 79, 80]
```

Why I have Unexpected token ? Any ideas?

b) Could you suggest a way to parse correctly the json response and **store each node of json
 into a different variable** ?

drawNo
   drawtime
   results

Comment: Cross-origin? If so, the server probably needs to support JSONP instead of raw JSON. `{"a":"b", ...}` is not valid Javascript code, and hence the error.

Comment: That could be the first object in responce, which has time with `:`.

Comment: You are not using JSON. You are using JSONP since the server doesn't seem to support cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making a cross-origin call with a `callback` argument. This means you are using JSONP.

The response you are getting is JSON, not JSONP.

Trying to parse JSON as JSONP will throw an error.

The API you are accessing doesn't appear to support anything that will enable a cross-origin request. Get data from it using your server instead of your visitors' browsers.

Comment: You say that the call back function has the problem right? How did you determne that the API doesn't support cross-origin request? Since In the tab network in Chrome I have a response. Is there a way to get this response in Javascript local variables through jquery ?

Comment: "You say that the call back function has the problem right?" — No, the problem is that the API doesn't call your callback function at all.

Comment: "How did you determne that the API doesn't support cross-origin request?" — I looked at it and did not see evidence of JSONP or CORS.

Comment: "Since In the tab network in Chrome I have a response." — That means nothing. The network tab is under the control of the owner of the browser. The only parties involved are the browser owner and the site owner. JavaScript on a website is under the control of another website author. The other website author is not, by default, allowed to read the data sent to the browser owner by the first website.

Comment: "Is there a way to get this response in Javascript local variables through jquery ?" — [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 — The server doesn't support JSONP, that's the point of the question.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you very much for clearing me the facts.Probably this API is not ideal in order to practise with cross-origin-requests because it doesn't support JSONP or CORS as you said. I will try to find something else. Thanks again for your attitude!